# Dividing Hypercubes into $n$ smaller Hypercubes

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, logic, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Name a positive integer $n$ *nice* if a square can be divided into $n$ smaller squares. The smaller squares do not need to be of the same size. Since you can always divide a square into $4$ smaller squares it immediately follows, that if $n$ is *nice* $n+3$ has to be aswell. Since $6, 7$ and $8$ are *nice* all natural numbers greater than $8$ have to be *nice*.

This got me thinking about the same problem in higher Dimensions. 
Let $n_d$ be *nice* if it divides a Hypercube in $d$ Dimensions into $n_d$ smaller Hypercubes.

Does for all Dimensions $d$ exist a $n_d$ such that all numbers greater than $n_d$ are *nice*? Is there a simple way to determine wether a number is *nice* in $d$ Dimensions or not?

Comment: By the same argument you get that in dimension $d$, if $n$ is nice also $n+2^d-1$ is nice. Also, the only number smaller than $2^d$ that is nice is $1$. But this doesn't help a lot, I guess.

Comment: How do you divide a square in $6$ squares?

Comment: @ajotatxe: Divide a $3 \times 3$ square into one $2 \times 2$ and five $1 \times 1$.

Comment: $8$ is a bit harder: see [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/problems/8square.png)

Comment: @RobertIsrael Wouldn't a $4\times4$ divided into one $3\times3$ and seven $1\times1$ squares also be a dissection into $8$ squares?

Comment: Oh, of course...

Comment: It is not hard to see that there exists $n_d$ such that all $n\ge n_d$ are *nice*. The hard problem is, finding all *nice* $n\lt n_d$: [For what natural n does there exist a cube composed of n cubes and more](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3497867/318073).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $k$, you can divide a hypercube into $k^d$ equal hypercubes.
Thus if $n$ is nice, so is $n + k^d-1$.  Now $2^d-1$ and $(2^d-1)^d-1$ are coprime, so any sufficiently large integer can be expressed as $1 + m (2^d-1) + n ((2^d-1)^d-1)$ for some $m$ and $n$, and thus is nice.

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ are coprime, any positive integer $N\ge (p-1)(q-1)$ can be written as $N=ap+bq$ for non-negative integers $a,b$.